# jquery images align center on position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help in JQuery. 
I have some div-elements with pictures of different sizes inside. 
They are arranged in absolute position (bottom: 0). I want that only smaller images of the div container are positioned at the center (horizontal).

```
var image = $(".inner img");
var box = $('.inner').width();
var wimage = image.width();
var total = (box - wimage) / 2;


if(wimage <= 190 ){
   image.css('margin-left', total);
}
```

[Fiddle for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3XM66/).

Thank you all for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be like this:

```
var image = $(".inner img");



image.each(function(){
    var wimage = $(this).width();
    var box = $('.inner').width();
    var total = (box / 2) - (wimage / 2);

    //console.log(wimage);
    //console.log(box);
    //console.log(total);

    if(wimage <= 190 ){
       $(this).css('left', total);
    }
});
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/3XM66/4/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were after?

http://jsfiddle.net/3XM66/1/

**JS**

```
$('.inner img').each(function () {
    var imgWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).css('margin-left', imgWidth / 2 * -1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".inner").each(function(){
var image = $(this).find("img");
var box = $(this).width();
var wimage = image.width();
var total = (box - wimage) / 2;
    if(wimage <= 190 ){
    image.css('margin-left', total);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".inner img").each(function(index, Element){
    var image = $(Element);
    image.css('margin-left', (image.parent().parent().width() - image.width())/2);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XM66/5/